# how can i store each items in a json array using c#

Tags: c#, json

I want to store each item to a json array which is placed inside a foreach loop.How can i possible?

Presently my code is

```
foreach (DataRow drow1 in alltheatre.Rows)
        {
            string theatname = drow1["TheatreName"].ToString();
            string latitude = drow1["Latitude"].ToString();
            string longitude = drow1["Longitude"].ToString();
            string theatname = drow1["TheatreName"].ToString();
            string theatid = drow1["TheatreDetailsId"].ToString();
            string theataddre = drow1["TheatreAddress"].ToString();
            string cntctnu = drow1["ContactNum"].ToString();
            string theatimg = drow1["TheatreImage"].ToString();
            string descr = drow1["TheatreDesc"].ToString();
            string mouvieid = drow1["MovieMasterId"].ToString();

                 array = new[]
                        {
                           new
                            {
                           Name = theatname,
                           Theatrdetailsid=theatid,
                           image=theatimg,
                           lat=latitude,
                           longi=longitude,
                           adress=theataddre,
                           contactnum=cntctnu,
                           desc=descr,
                            }
                          },
                        }
                      }
```

Here,i have a foreach loop for getting details about a theatre,i tried to store each data to a json array,but i can only managed to store 1 data,ie the last one.How to resolve this issue.

Comment: You are always initializing your array object. that's why only the last record persist.

Comment: @user1672994:give me any solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your new collection outside of the `foreach` loop. You only have one, because creates a new array every time.

Instead of an array, you should use a `List<T>`. This will be much easier, unless you want to use LINQ or create an array the size of the `Rows` collection.

```
var array = new List<object>();

foreach (var row in alltheatre.Rows)
{
    // Get your properties

    array.Add(new 
    {
        // Set your properties
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [LINQ's Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) to map each row:

```
IEnumerable<object> mapped = alltheatre.Rows.Select(row => new 
{
     Name = row["TheatreName"].ToString(),
     Theatrdetailsid = row["TheatreDetailsId"].ToString()
     // ...
});
```

If you need it to be in a raw array, you can call [ToArray()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb298736(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
object[] mappedArray = mapped.ToArray();
```